# How can i fetch the values from Login control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i fetch the values entered for ID and password in the login control provided at the login page to be used further in my page? I want those values at my .cs page. Please give answer in c# language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx) control exposes [UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.username.aspx) and [Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.password.aspx) properties.

Comment: I am using FormsAuthentication.authenticate() method and i am able to use the the username and password, but its navigating me to default.aspx, i want to change it yo HomePage.aspx, how can i do that? is there any where i can set in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in aspx page:

```
<asp:Login runat="server" ID="lc" OnAuthenticate="lc_Authenticate"></asp:Login>
```

in aspx.cs page:

```
protected void lc_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    e.Authenticated = DoValidate(lc.UserName, lc.Password);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting DoValidate function, is there any name space that i need to add?

Comment: No It's just a method for validaton the username and password which you provide.